if a file is selected then display something in html/javascript
I want if a user select an image within <input type='file'> then display the image right next to the input for the user to know that the picture has been uploaded successfully. and I want to use HTML and JAVASCRIPT for this matter.
I have searched internet for it but got nothing from it

Can't really have searched hard, quick google for "reading file from input" you get something like FileReader, which you can use to get a base64 URL, which you can use a a source for an <img /> element. Or even just use const img = document.body.appendChild( new Image ); img.src = URL.createObjectURL( input.files[0] ) is even easier.

Does this answer your question? Preview an image before it is uploaded



    document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      if (file) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          const img = document.getElementById('imagePreview');
          img.src = e.target.result;
          img.style.display = 'block';
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    });
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Image Preview</title>
  <style>
    .preview-container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .preview-container img {
      max-width: 100px; /* Adjust as needed */
      max-height: 100px; /* Adjust as needed */
      margin-left: 20px; /* Space between input and image */
      border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Optional styling */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="preview-container">
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" accept="image/*">
    <img id="imagePreview" src="#" alt="Image Preview" style="display: none;">
  </div>

  
</body>
</html>



